# Selenium - Properly Implementing Multithreading and/or Processing

Tags: python, selenium

I have been learning Python and Selenium and decided to give myself a project to build a program that checks online product stock across a variety of websites. Specifically, I am wanting to implement multithreading to allow concurrent lookups of each website. The relevant excerpt of my code is below. There's more involved but I think the below captures the questions I have. Hopefully it's not too confusing but the gist of it is:

1. Execute both _BB_Scrape and _GS_Scrape methods concurrently.
2. Both methods go through steps to initially open and navigate to the webpage I want to scrape
3. Both methods then call the _refresh_loop. This is where my question lies. In my head it makes sense to just refresh the page over and over to check for product availability (which is what _refresh_loop does) instead of re-opening the webpage again and again. However, I do not know how this would work with 2 threads accessing the same function. If the bb_thread accesses _refresh_loop with it's specific arguments, is it possible for gs_thread to also access _refresh_loop with it's specific arguments as well? If that makes sense? Basically I want both threads to concurrently refresh their respective webpages. Hopefully any of this makes sense.

Thanks a lot

```
    def main(self):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            bb_thread = executor.submit(self._BB_Scrape, self.BB_driver, "BestBuy")
            gs_thread = executor.submit(self._GS_Scrape, self.GS_driver, "GameStop") 

    @_delay_wrapper(5)
    def _BB_Scrape(self, driver, vendor):
        '''BestBuy Scraper Method'''
        driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.ca/")
        search = driver.find_element(*PageLocators.BB_SEARCH_LOCATOR); search.send_keys("Playstation 5"); search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(PageLocators.BB_PS5_LOCATOR))
            driver.find_element(*(PageLocators.BB_PS5_LOCATOR)).click()

        except (selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException, selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException):
            self.logger.error(f"{vendor} - Timeout. Failed to find BB_PS5_LOCATOR or Element Obscuring Error")
            self._refresh_driver(driver, f"{vendor} - Timeout. Failed to find BB_PS5_LOCATOR or Element Obscuring Error", True)
            return

        self._refresh_loop(driver, vendor, 300)
        self._refresh_driver(driver)

    @_delay_wrapper(5)
    def _GS_Scrape(self, driver, vendor):
        '''GameStop Scraper Method'''
        driver.set_window_size(700,700); driver.get('https://www.gamestop.ca')
        search = driver.find_element(*PageLocators.GS_SEARCH_LOCATOR); search.send_keys("Playstation 5 Only"); search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(PageLocators.GS_PS5_LOCATOR))
            act = ActionChains(driver); act.move_to_element(element); act.click(); act.perform()

        except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
            self.logger.error(f"{vendor} - Timeout. Failed to find GS_PS5_LOCATOR")
            self._refresh_driver(driver, f"{vendor} - Timeout. Failed to find GS_PS5_LOCATOR", True)
            return

        self._refresh_loop(driver, vendor, 300)
        self._refresh_driver(driver)

    def _refresh_loop(self, driver, vendor, num):
        for _ in range(num):
            response = self._check_availability(driver, vendor)
            if response[0]: self._discord_call(vendor, response[1], response[2], "PS5 Disk Edition", WebScraper.THUMBNAIL)
            driver.refresh(); sleep(10)
        return

    def _check_availability(self, driver, vendor):
        if vendor in ["BestBuy", "GameStop"]:
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(WebScraper.DICT.get(vendor)))
                self.logger.info(f"{vendor} - Unavailable")
                return False, None, None

            except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
                self.logger.info(f"{vendor} - Available")
                return True, driver.current_url, "$629.99"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Selenium with Python, there's a framework called [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) that uses the `pytest-xdist` library for multithreading Selenium tests in a reliable way.

When multithreading tests with `pytest`, you would specify the number of processes used like this:

```sh
pytest -n=4
```

(The above creates 4 parallel processes for running `pytest` tests.)

Tests will be more simplified than you're used to, but there are plenty of examples in the [SeleniumBase examples/ folder](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/tree/master/examples).